# Proxies not set according to preferences on Eclipse RCP startup

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've added `org.eclipse.core.net` and `org.eclipse.ui.net` to my RCP application. According to [this comment](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/12/08/eclipse-rcp-proxy-preference/#comment-1502), this should be enough to set the Java system properties. But in my case, the properties are only set after I open the `Network connections` preference page. The problem is that the `org.eclipse.*.net` plugins aren't getting activated. Is there a more correct way to fix this than just loading a random class from these plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like the Eclipse IDE does it.
See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService()` in bundle `org.eclipse.ui.ide.application`